# "Soma e adição são a mesma operação" ou "soma e adição é a mesma operação"?

Tags: gramática, concordância-nominal

Qual destas frases é a correta?

> - Soma e adição **são** a mesma operação.
> - Soma e adição **é** a mesma operação.

Considerando que o termo "soma e adição" é um sintagma nominal plural (eles são a mesma operação), penso que a primeira forma é a correta, mas me soa muito estranho.

Já operação é singular. Será que o verbo de ligação pode concordar com o segundo termo?

Qual a forma correta?

---

Depois da discussão nos comentários, eu decidi pesquisar numas apostilas antigas que tenho, e encontrei a seguinte particularidade:

> Quando o sujeito composto é formado por núcleos sinônimos ou quase sinônimos, o verbo pode ficar no plural ou no singular.

Por Exemplo:

> Descaso e desprezo marcam / marca seu comportamento.

Mantenho a pergunta, essa mesma regra se aplica para verbo de ligação?

Answer (score 4):

Resposta curta, porém precisa:

> Clarke Kent e o Superman **são** a mesma pessoa.
>
> **Eles** são a mesma pessoa.
>
> Soma e adição **são** a mesma operação.
>
> Elas são a mesma operação.

[**Concordância verbal**](https://www.todamateria.com.br/concordancia-verbal/) - Concordância verbal é a relação estabelecida de forma harmônica entre sujeito e verbo. Isso quer dizer que quando o sujeito está no singular, o verbo também deve estar; quando o sujeito estiver no plural, o verbo também estará.

Comment: Sim, concordo. Mas _porquê_? E se vier alguém e responder apenas "resposta curta, porém precisa: FCP e Benfica é tudo a mesma corja."? Decidimos qual a resposta correta, consoante o número de _upvotes_? Mas e se o comum dos votantes for um ignorante, e votar errado? Como pode um leitor crítico mas que não saiba a resposta, confiar? :)

Comment: @ANeves, a pergunta é elementar e a resposta está de acordo.  A resposta mostra de forma nada sutil, o óbvio: que o verbo tem que concordar com o sujeito em número. Na sua frase,  "tudo" não tem plural, e eu colocaria uma vírgula depois de Benfica.  Além do mais há uma inversão, a saber, "tudo é a mesma corja".  De qualquer forma vou expandir.  Sei que com moderador não se discute, mas o senhor está errado. Os Dragões, Azuis e Brancos,  estão bem acima da ralé.  :-)

Comment: Realmente, uma explicação mais adequada, com explicações, seria interessante. Pois nesse caso o verbo é de ligação, estabelece uma certa relação de igualdade. Por exemplo: "a operação em questão é soma e adição, as quais são a mesma.". Aceitei como resposta para não ser chato.

Comment: Para mim está ótimo como está agora! Obrigado pelas melhorias, toma um voto-acima.

Comment: (Se calhar levavas era um voto-abaixo, para aprenderes a não regurgitar barbaridades como "com moderador não se discute". :p Que quanto mais responsabilidade tenho, mais preciso que me questionem para eu ter a certeza que não estou a fazer asneira, ehm! )